# Filter str_detect does not equal

Tags: string, dplyr

I'm attempting to filter for values of a character variable `var` that **do not contain** a period (.) within them. I'm trying something like:

```
d <- d %>% 
  filter(
    str_detect(var, !".")
  )
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I assume this is an easy fix but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_detect` searches for matches using regular expressions, and in regular expressions `.` means "any character". You'll need to use `\\.` so that the period is recognized literally. And your negation is in the wrong place:

```
d %>% 
    filter(
        !str_detect(var, "\\.")
    )
```

`str_detect` also has a "negate" argument that returns results that do not match the provided pattern. This is equivalent to the above:

```
d %>% 
    filter(
        str_detect(var, "\\.", negate = T)
    )
```

Comment: Makes much more sense, thanks.